# PushViewController in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In My App My Root View Controller is TabBar 
in one Of TabBar Controller i Use table View i wanna push View Controller when Press To Cell 
but when i use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  TripDetailView * TripDetailViewObjec = [[TripDetailView alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TripDetailViewObjec animated:YES];
}
```

doesn't do any thing this because `Self.navigation=null`

and i try to Create UINavigationController  in AppDelegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate * ApplicationDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        [[ApplicationDelegate Nav] pushViewController:TripDetailViewObjec animated:YES];
}
```

My AppDelegate

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    WeekendTrips * WeekendTripsObject ; 
    UINavigationController * Nav;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic)   UINavigationController * Nav;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize Nav;

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
WeekendTripsObject = [[WeekendTrips alloc]init];

    Nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:WeekendTripsObject];
   [self.view addSubView Nav.view];
    return YES;
}
```

and this doesn't work 
what i can do ?
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Instance of `UINavigationController` inside your appdelegate.
And you need to add a navigation bar in your view in the tab bar controller.

If you have a tab bar in the xib, drag a `UINavigationController` object over from the Library window into the Tree View for your tab bar. Place the navigation controller inside the tab bar controller, then drag your existing view controller inside the navigation controller.

If you are creating the tabbar programmatically it's quite simple:

Do like:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yournib1" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationcontroller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yournib2" bundle:nil];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationcontroller, viewController2, nil];
```

Please refer this [tutorial](http://codenugget.org/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a)

Comment: Really Thank You Midhun ... I ASk You more questions Till Now

Comment: @TefaMohamed: it's ok dude :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an **`UINaviatigationController` as your applications root view controller and then add the first table view** as the navigation root view of the navigation controller. Then you can push other table views with `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]`.

Comment: if i make this my rootviewcontroller will change to table view and i wanna keep my rootviewcontroller is TabBar

Comment: I know it's a bit confusing topic, but please read it carefully. There is a difference between the root view controller of the application (which should be the UINavigationController) and the root view controller of the navigation controller (which should be the UITableViewController)!